# How make a content in a row be centred " \multicolumn{1}{l}{Difference} & Mean"

Tags: tables, tabularx

Basically, I want the word `Difference` to be located at the center like the picture draw below `located in the square box`.

[image]

I am using

```
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Difference} & Mean
```

I changed to

```
  \multirow{3}{l}{Difference} & Mean
```

But not working.

My Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XcS[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=1.5]}
    \toprule
    & & & {\thead{Statistic}}& {\thead{Std. Error}} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Difference} & Mean
    & & 30.9524 & 5.864 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & \multirow{2}{=}{95\% Confidence Interval for Mean} & Lower Bound & 17.6861 & \\
\cmidrule{3-5}
    & & Upper Bound & \ 44.2186 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & 5\% Trimmed Mean & & 31.7460 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Median & & 30.9524 \\
\cmidrule{2-5} 
    & Range & & 66.6667 \\
\cmidrule{2-5} 
    & Interquartile Range & & 25.0000 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}     
    & Skewness & & -0.8959 & 0.687 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}     
    & Kurtosis & & 1.8087 & 1.334 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, with `multirow`. I took the opportunity to improve the vertical centring of the other multirow, using decimal values for the ‘number’ of lines (to take into account the vertical padding of booktabs rules).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XcS[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=1.5]}
    \toprule
    & & & {\thead{Statistic}}& {\thead{Std. Error}} \\
\midrule
    \multirow{12.2}{*}{Difference} & Mean
    & & 30.9524 & 5.864 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & \multirow{2.4}{=}{95\% Confidence Interval for Mean} & Lower Bound & 17.6861 & \\
\cmidrule{3-5}
    & & Upper Bound & \ 44.2186 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & 5\% Trimmed Mean & & 31.7460 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Median & & 30.9524 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Range & & 66.6667 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Interquartile Range & & 25.0000 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Skewness & & -0.8959 & 0.687 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Kurtosis & & 1.8087 & 1.334 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Sorry to ask again. Which part `using decimal values for the ‘number’ of line`. I only see `\multirow{12.2}{*}{Difference} & Mean`. I think i am too tired.

Comment: i think i found it. It is `& \multirow{2.4}{=}{95\% Confidence Interval for Mean}` part that you change from `2.0` to `2.4`.

Comment: Yes, to compensate the padding of the rules. By trial and error, of course.